# What happens after you have completed all agency missions in Just Cause 2?

Tags: just-cause-2

I have still 2 Agency Missions to complete in `Just Cause 2`. But I would also like to reach a good completion percentage, so what happens after I finish all agency missions?

Can I continue to destroy bases and do faction missions or does the game simply end there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes..... the game doesn't end.  It's open-ended =)

**SPOILER ALERT**

After you are done with all agency missions (cool ending, too), you will enter what is called the **Mercenary Mode**, at which point your only goal is to reach the 100% of the entire game, including faction missions and takeovers.

You will then find yourself (at least it happened to me) making your own goals, such as:

- I will take over all airports
- I will have full stars on all weapons and vehicles
- I will fly to the highest mountain and parachute down
- I will drive a fast car off a cliff

.......... It's never ending.

Comment: Great, thank you. I really love this game approach, hope to see more sandbox game like this in future.